# How to mock object where single interface is implemented by multiple classes

Tags: c#, moq, autofac, xunit, .net-4.8

I have one interface with multiple classes implementation. I have registered them in Autofac Container. My PaymentService class takes two parameters where one of them can implement multiple classes. How to mock to specific class??

Interface

```
public interface IAccountDataStorage
{
    Account GetAccount(string accountNumber);
    void UpdateAccount(Account account);
}
```

Implemented classes

```
public class BackupAccountDataStore : IAccountDataStorage
{
     ...
}

public class AccountDataStore : IAccountDataStorage
{
     ...
}
```

Register in Autofac container

```
 builder.RegisterType<AccountDataStore>().Keyed("defaultAccountStorage", typeof(IAccountDataStorage));
 builder.RegisterType<BackupAccountDataStore>().Keyed("backupAccountStorage", typeof(IAccountDataStorage));
```

To Resolve Interface of the specific class

```
var a = buildContainer.ResolveKeyed<IAccountDataStorage>("defaultAccountStorage");
var b = buildContainer.ResolveKeyed<IAccountDataStorage>("backupAccountStorage");
```

Test class

```
public class MakePaymentTest
{
    private readonly PaymentService sut;
    private readonly Mock<IAppAmbientState> mockAppAmbientState = new Mock<IAppAmbientState>();
    //private readonly Mock<IAccountDataStorage> mockAccountDataStorage = new Mock<IAccountDataStorage>();


    public MakePaymentTest()
    {
        mockAppAmbientState.Object.AppSettingsRepository = new App.SharedKernel.Values.AppConfiguration
        {
            DataStoreType = "Backup"
        };

        //Need help here
        sut = new PaymentService(mockAppAmbientState.Object, ???????); // let say I want mock AccountDataStore here...
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MakePayment_Should_ReturnTypeOf_MakePaymentResult()
    {
        //Arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var mockMakePaymentRequest = fixture.Create<MakePaymentRequest>();


        //Act
        var actualDataResult = sut.MakePayment(mockMakePaymentRequest);

        //Assert

    }
```

Comment: Please show the constructor definition of `PaymentService`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not Mock a specific implementation. You mock return values

```
sut = new PaymentService(mockAppAmbientState.Object, ???????); // let say I want mock AccountDataStore here...
```

What you must do, is make the first and second mock objects, return the proper values for your unit test to follow the needed code paths.

The concrete implementations of the classes, will be tested in their own classes.

The whole idea of the following line, is to use the abstraction and handle the return values. So any link to the actual concrete implementation, beats the point of mocking in the first place.

```
private readonly Mock<IAccountDataStorage> mockAccountDataStorage = new Mock<IAccountDataStorage>();
```

Comment: so my main question is! I want to test AccountDataStore and not BackupAccountDataStore which implements IAccountDataStorage so how I do that? many thanks in advance

Comment: You test the instance of the `AccountDataStore`. A new file for those tests that mocks the external dependencies required by the `AccountDataStore`